# MongoDB Limit fields and slice projection together

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following User object:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("someId"),
  "name" : "Bob",
  "password" : "fakePassword",
  "follower" : [...],
  "following" : [..]
}
```

I need to paginate over the follower list, so I use the slice projection operator, but I just need the paginated followers list to be returned. And I don't know if I am doing it the wrong way, or this can't be done, but limit fields doesn't work with slice projection.

Following are a couple of queries I tried:

```
 collection.findOne(
          {
            _id: new ObjectId(userId)
          },
          {
            follower: {$slice:[skip, parseInt(pageSize)]},
            follower: 1
          },..
```

and

```
collection.findOne(
          {
            _id: new ObjectId(userId)
          },
          {
            follower: 1,
            follower: {$slice:[skip, parseInt(pageSize)]}
          },
```

But these return all the values in the object, and does not limit the fields, although, the slice works fine in both the cases.
Also when I do something like `_id:0,following:0` , this part works, but I don't want to mention each and every field in the query like this, it may create problems once I decide to change the schema. 
How do I get this to work, what could be the syntax for the query to get this working..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure I'm getting your usage pattern here. Perhaps we can simplify the example a little. So considering the document:

```js
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("537dd763f95ddda3208798c5"),
    "name" : "Bob",
    "password" : "fakePassword",
    "follower" : [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C",
            "D",
            "E",
            "F",
            "G",
            "H",
            "I",
            "J",
            "K"
    ]
}
```

So the simple query like this:

```js
db.paging.find(
    { "name": "Bob" },
    { 
        "_id": 0, 
        "name": 0, 
        "password": 0, 
        "follower": { "$slice": [0,3] } 
}).pretty()
```

Gives results:

```js
{
    "follower" : [
            "A",
            "B",
            "C"
    ]
}
```

And similarly from the following page:

```js
db.paging.find(
    { "name": "Bob" },
    { 
        "_id": 0, 
        "name": 0, 
        "password": 0, 
        "follower": { "$slice": [3,3] } 
}).pretty()
```

Gives the results:

```js
{ 
    "follower" : [ 
        "D", 
        "E", 
        "F" 
    ]
}
```

So for me personally I am not sure whether you were asking about the field exclusion or whether you were asking about "paging" the array results, but either way, both of those examples are shown here.

Comment: So like in your answer, you had to define all the fields that you need to remove, but according to the mongodb docs, you can also just specify the fields that you need, like `followers:1`, So that will just give me the followers field, and the _id field, and I do not have to specify every other field that I don't need. I need this to work with the slice projection operator.

Comment: @SambhavSharma If that is your actual question then I will happily submit the documentation patch ( already a contributor ) but no this actually does not work this way. You need to explicitly exclude all of the fields you do not want when using `$slice`. You also cannot mix inclusion and exclusion under `.find()` and if you need that complexity then you use [`.aggregate()`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/) with the [**`$project`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) operator instead.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to actually use _id here by saying `{_id:1}`:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("537de1bc08eb9d89a7d3a1b2"), "f" : [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20 ], "d" : 1 }
> db.test.findOne({ "_id" : ObjectId("537de1bc08eb9d89a7d3a1b2")},{f:{$slice:[0,2]}})
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("537de1bc08eb9d89a7d3a1b2"),
        "f" : [
                1,
                2
        ],
        "d" : 1
}
> db.test.findOne({ "_id" : ObjectId("537de1bc08eb9d89a7d3a1b2")},{_id:0, f:{$slice:[0,2]}})
{ "f" : [ 1, 2 ], "d" : 1 }
> db.test.findOne({ "_id" : ObjectId("537de1bc08eb9d89a7d3a1b2")},{_id:1, f:{$slice:[0,2]}})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("537de1bc08eb9d89a7d3a1b2"), "f" : [ 1, 2 ] }
```

Comment: I think this should be marked the right answer. Also if you absolutely don't want _id, you can set _id: 0 and some nonexistent_field: 1. It seems unlikely that having _id in the returned doc would be a problem though. One more thing; if you're slicing in a subdocument like sub_doc.my_array: {$slice ...} you need to select a nonexistent field at that level like sub_doc.nonexistant_field: 1 to prevent getting more than just the slice